# Seamless conversion from kg to lb and lb to kg client side

Tags: javascript

I have set up a function to take care of my metric conversion an it's not so seamless. I would like to convert lbs to kg and kg to lbs. The problem that i am having is using the jquery change function. It's causing the conversion to only happen on a change but sometimes i just want to due back to back conversions from lbs to kg and it gets stuck and convert the lbs to more lbs or kg to more kg. Any help is appreciated. here is my code below

```
$("#wUnits").change(function () {
        var approx = 2.2;
        if ($(this).val() == "lbs") {
            value = $("#txtWeight").val() / approx;
            $('#wValue').val(value.toFixed(2));
        } else if ($(this).val() == "kg") {
            value = $("#txtWeight").val() * approx;
            $('#wValue').val(value.toFixed(2));
        } else {
            var value = "";
            $('#wValue').val(value);
        }
    });
```

and below is my markup

```
<select id="wUnits">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="lbs">lbs</option>
<option value="kg">kg</option>
    </select>
```

Ideally what i would like to acheive is a seamless transition between conversions using a dropdown.

Comment: can you post a fiddle of the problem in action?

Comment: @user2544318 if you take what i have and add it to jsfiddle you should be able to reproduce the occurrence/issue.

Comment: [Your code seems to be doing what you want it to do](http://jsfiddle.net/z23Gg/), although the UI looks confusing (if I got it right).

Comment: I wrote up your code in http://jsfiddle.net/3ZQUB/ and it appears to work fine. The value in txtWeight properly gets converted based on the selected unit.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz if you look at your solution first type in 215 which is lbs and do a conversion to kg you should get 97.73 and then try the reverse. Its not producing an accurate seamless conversion

Comment: @DavidPeterson The problem is due to floating point error. 215 lb is not 97.73 kg, it's 97.7272727273. That is why you would never get the expected values.

Comment: -1 for expecting each of us to build the jsfiddle for you (especially as it's not clear what ids such as txtWeight or wValue represent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want the conversion to happen not just when you change the value of the `<select>`

I changed your code a little, it's good to cache the variables in this case, also, I separated the function code to a function named `conversion` that is triggered on both the `<select>` change and on `keyup` or `change` on your `#txtWeight` input.

**EDIT**, implementing **Jason Sperske**'s idea, and added an extra `<span>` with the resulting units, to avoid confusion. It should be:

HTML:

```
  Convert <input type="text" id="txtWeight" />
  <select id="wUnits"><br>
    <option value="0">--</option>
    <option value="0.45359237">lbs</option>
    <option value="2.2">kg</option>
  </select><br>
  Result: <input type="text" id="wValue" /><span id='rUnits'
```

JS:

```
var $units = $("#wUnits");
var $wvalue = $('#wValue');
var $txtweight = $("#txtWeight");
var $runits = $('#rUnits');

$units.change(conversion);
$txtweight.on('keyup change',conversion);

function conversion () {
  var value = $txtweight.val() * $units.val();
  if(value !== 0) {
    $wvalue.val(value.toFixed(2));
    $runits.text($units.children(':gt(0):not(:selected)').text());
  } else {
    $wvalue.val("");
    $runits.text('');
  }
}
```

[**<kbd>JSBin Demo</kbd>**](http://jsbin.com/AVOSOBo/3/edit)

Comment: if you  go to your solution on JSBin if you put in 215.00 it gives you 97.73 on lbs which is actually a conversion to kg

Comment: Why not just bake the conversion ratio into the select list like this: http://jsbin.com/AVOSOBo/1/

Comment: @JasonSperske if you take the solution that you have presented and add 9.00 lbs and do a conversion to kg it should yeild 19.80 then try to take 215 lbs and convert to kg it should yeild 97.73 but it's producing 44.32

Comment: @JasonSperske Good Idea, I updated the answer to reflect that :)